# how to get access and read message_t data tinyos

Tags: sensors, tinyos

hello every one i want to ask you if you know a way to extract data from message_t
in the oldest version of TinyOs there are TOS_Msg and TOS_MsgPtr but in message_t i could't find a way please help me
and i want to know if there is any data type to store data like table or array list

```
typedef nx_struct message_localization{
    nx_uint8_t   NodeId;
    bool       ancre_nature;
    nx_uint8_t   x_coordinate;
    nx_uint8_t   y_coordinate; 
    x_uint8_t   energie_transmited;

 } message_localization_t;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Packet` interface has a command `getPayload` which does want you want:

```
command void *getPayload(message_t *msg, uint8_t len);
```

See [the documentation](http://www.tinyos.net/tinyos-2.1.0/doc/nesdoc/iris/ihtml/tos.interfaces.Packet.html) for more information.

To access the data field, you may do as follows:

```
message_t msg;
message_localization_t *payload =
    (message_localization_t *)call Packet.getPayload(
        &msg, sizeof(message_localization_t));
payload->x_coordinate = x;
payload->y_coordinate = y;
/* and so on */
```

The same command is for convenience included in interfaces [`Send`](http://www.tinyos.net/tinyos-2.1.0/doc/nesdoc/iris/ihtml/tos.interfaces.Send.html) and [`AMSend`](http://www.tinyos.net/tinyos-2.1.0/doc/nesdoc/iris/ihtml/tos.interfaces.AMSend.html). `Packet` and `AMSend` are provided by the [`ActiveMessageC`](http://www.tinyos.net/tinyos-2.x/doc/nesdoc/telosb/chtml/tos.platforms.telosa.ActiveMessageC.html) configuration.